# Calculation of 3-phase power in Electric Vehicle Charging

Tags: power, battery-charging, charger, rectifier, three-phase

I have a doubt regarding calculation of 3-phase power in EV charging. On the last page of the pdf in the link given below, the power calculation is done as 3 x 230V x 16A = 22kW.

http://www3.fronius.com/cps/rde/xbcr/SID-673FE905-375C8296/fronius_australia/Why_three_phase____An_overview_of_the_benefits_of_a_three_phase_network_1195856_snapshot.pdf

However, I don't understand why is it not √3 x 230V x 16A or 400V x 16A instead. Can somebody explain the calculations with the reason for the same?

Comment: Have you read the Wikipedia page on 3-phase power: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-phase_electric_power ? Note how there are the Y-configuration and the Delta configuration. The calculation would be valid for the Y-configuration as phase to neutral is 230 V.

Comment: Yes, I do know about three phase power. Something made me confused for a while and I managed to make a fool of myself by asking this rather stupid question. Btw, can you please tell about what type of (3-phase) rectifier is used in EVs? 6-pulse or a 12-pulse?

Comment: I expect the rectifier not to be in the vehicle itself but in the charging console. I could be wrong though. For a Y-configuration I would expect a 6-pulse rectifier, again I could be wrong. What is used isn't always like *if this - then that* as it can depend on circumstances and design choices. Understanding the **why** behind those choices is much more interesting and useful than just learning *what* is used *when*.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Well, the rectifier sits inside the car for AC charging (also called onboard charger). For DC fast charging, the rectification is done by the charger (at charging station) as the onboard charger's power electronics are not meant to deal with high power. While DC charging, the DC current is bypassed (I don't know how this actually works) directly to the battery.

Comment: You mentioned that for a Y-configuration, you expected a 6-pulse configuration. Why is it so? Am I missing something basic here or is it out of experience?

Comment: Almost certainly what is really done is three single phase power factor corrected switchmode converters star connected. 6 and 12 pulse are terms that apply to old school diode bridges with delta-star transformers (for 12 pulse) or other heavy magnetics. The power factor of such supplies is markedly inferior to that of a good PFC switcher.  For the on vehicle stuff weight is the critical consideration, and a high frequency switched mode design with PFC input will always be lighter then line frequency iron.

Comment: @DanMills Can you please provide a link from where I can study about "three single-phase power factor corrected switchmode converters star connected" as you mentioned. I never read about it (since we haven't been taught power electronics yet and so I have to rely on self-study).

Comment: Well a single phase power factor corrected supply is a totally standard thing, so putting three of them star connected is not exactly non obvious if you have a three phase supply, and is a very standard approach. Most on vehicle chargers are probably single phase however, in which case a single modern switched mode PFC corrected supply is quite sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phase to phase voltage is 400V, which gives 230V phase to neutral voltage. \$\dfrac{400}{\sqrt3} = 230\$.

So the formula is \$\dfrac{400}{\sqrt3}\cdot 3\cdot16 = \dfrac{\sqrt3}{\sqrt3\sqrt3}400 \cdot3\cdot16 =400 \sqrt3\cdot16\$. Or \$230 \cdot3\cdot16\$

Comment: Oh Yes! I don't know why I felt confused at seeing something very obvious. Thanks for the clarification though!

Comment: Btw, can you please tell about what type of (3-phase) rectifier is used in EVs? 6-pulse or a 12-pulse?

Comment: @PMD It doesn't matter what's behind, since you are measuring the three phase input.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter for power calculations. Asked that for a different purpose i.e. to know what harmonics would be introduced by the charger....

Comment: @PMD You would need a transformer set for 12 pulse rectifier, which is heavy and big. There are other methods, like PFC corrector: LC with IGBT/MOSFET combined with EMI filter.

Comment: @PMD You can assume six-pulse but with PFC.

Comment: Thanks MarkoBuršič and winny. Had this thing in mind for quite a few days and you helped clear it a bit

Comment: @PMD You're welcome. IMO you should try a six-pulse rectifier, and only then start to complicate things. There is also passive PFC and so on. It also depends on switching frequency of the charger about to install the line filter in the car or maybe outside. A filter might be more needed than PFC. There are only few PFC converters used in industrial environment today and expensive, meanwhile six pulse rect. and filter is very common - look for VFD and you'll see.